# Imageview clickevent gettag method in a listview row returns null

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, row, android-cursoradapter

I had an `ImageView` in a `listview` row, the `imageView` had a `clickevent` when i click an `imageview` the `getTag()` method is returning always `null`.

**My layout file:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 

    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/filename_mainlist"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filename_mainlist" 
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:max="100"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filename_mainlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="filename_mainlist" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filesize_maillist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:text="filesize" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/list_dropdown" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ListActionitemclick"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Customcursor adapter :**

```
    public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final int KB = 1024;
    private final int MG = KB * KB;
    private final int GB = MG * KB;     
    private String display_size;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewholder holder= (viewholder)arg0.getTag();
         holder.filename.setText(arg2.getString(arg2.getColumnIndex(arg2.getColumnName(1))));
         holder.filesize.setText(arg2.getString(arg2.getColumnIndex(arg2.getColumnName(2))));

                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(Util.getIcon(mContext, filetype));
           holder.progress.setProgress(arg2.getInt(arg2.getColumnIndex(arg2.getColumnName(3))));

        }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(arg0);

            View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlist_row,null);
           viewholder holder = new viewholder();
           holder.filename=(TextView)retView.findViewById(R.id.filename_mainlist);
           holder.filesize=(TextView)retView.findViewById(R.id.filesize_maillist);
           holder.icon=(ImageView)retView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           holder.dropdownicon=(ImageView)retView.findViewById(R.id.actionitem);
           holder.progress=(ProgressBar)retView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
           retView.setTag(holder);
            return retView;
    }

     class viewholder
    {
        TextView filename;
        TextView filesize;
        ImageView icon;
        ImageView dropdownicon;
        ProgressBar progress;
    }

}
```

**The actionitem clickevent:**

```
  public void ListActionitemclick(View v)
    {
    mSelectedRow = (Integer)v.getTag();// i am always getting a null value here
    mQuickAction.show(v);
    }
```

please help me out in solving this problem thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not getting any errors but the v.gettag is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that onItemClicked method of the listView is not called instead